# Css grid: horizontal two colums, but vertical flip

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-grid

I use

```
gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr))`,
```

to get two columns, if their width less than 250px, I get layout:

```
[1] [2]
```

And if the width is less than 250, I get layout:

```
[1]
[2]
```

I wonder if it is possible to have vertical layout flipped:

```
[2]
[1]
```

while keeping horizontal as described first `[1] [2]`.

Comment: It is not the size of the screen actually, but the width of the element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this particular case where there are only two *grid items*, you can *hack* it by mirroring the vertical direction in the *grid container* and inverting the mirror effect in the *grid items* - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
 display: grid;
 grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* set a row height for illustration */
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
 transform: scaleY(-1); /* mirror vertically */
}

.wrapper > div {
  background: aliceblue;
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform: scaleY(-1); /* straighten the grid item */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```